# Update products

Tags: product, database, upgrade

I need to update a product into magento.
I have write this:

```
function aggiornamento_prodotto ($cod_art,$data_inserimento,$attivo,$setTaxClassId,$prezzo_listino,$descrizione_estesa,$descrizione

require_once("../app/Mage.php");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$cod_art);

   //Product found, so we need to update it in Magento.

        $product->setName('$descrizione');
        $product->setPrice('$prezzo_listino');
        $product->setDescription('$descrizione_estesa');
        $product->setShortDescription('$descrizione');
    $product->setUpdatedAt(strtotime($data_inserimento);    
    $product->setStatus('$attivo');
    $product->setTaxClassId('$setTaxClassId');
try {
            $product->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
}


} 

$data_inserimento= strtotime ("now");
echo "start";
echo aggiornamento_prodotto('PR00088606',$data_inserimento,'1','2','234.938','questa è una descrizione estesa','questa è una descrizione corta');
echo "<br>end";
```

But not work.

Thanks
Ale

Answer (score 0):

**Code replace from**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$cod_art);

   //Product found, so we need to update it in Magento.

        $product->setName('$descrizione');
        $product->setPrice('$prezzo_listino');
        $product->setDescription('$descrizione_estesa');
        $product->setShortDescription('$descrizione');
    $product->setUpdatedAt(strtotime($data_inserimento);    
    $product->setStatus('$attivo');
    $product->setTaxClassId('$setTaxClassId');
try {
            $product->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
}
```

**TO**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$cod_art);

//Product found, so we need to update it in Magento.

$product->setName($descrizione);
$product->setPrice($prezzo_listino);
$product->setDescription($descrizione_estesa);
$product->setShortDescription($descrizione);
$product->setUpdatedAt(strtotime($data_inserimento);    
$product->setStatus($attivo);
$product->setTaxClassId($setTaxClassId);
try {
    $product->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
}
```

Comment: what has changed?